# xslt to generate desired output like following

Tags: xml, xslt

i am very new to XSLT. I would like to show xml data to parse based on **name and rno** matching attributes to be as follows.
Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent>
<child>
<name>test1</name>
<rno>101</rno>
<rating>2</rating>
</child>
<child>
<name>test2</name>
<rno>102</rno>
<rating>2</rating>
</child>
<child>
<name>test1</name>
 <rno>103</rno>
 <rating>2</rating>
 </child>
 <child>
 <name>test1</name>
 <rno>101</rno>
 <rating>1</rating>
 </child>
 </parent>
```

and i want output as follows:

```
 <parent>
 <child>
 <name>test1</name>
 <rno>101</rno>
 <sub-grp>
 <rating>2</rating>
 <rating>1</rating>
 <rating>2</rating>
 </sub-grp></child><child>
 <name>test2</name>
 <rno>102</rno> 
 <rating>2</rating>
 </child></parent>
```

Comment: This seems to be a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for reply  michael, currently i am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Have a read of http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and see how you get on

Comment: If you can move to XSLT 2.0, do so. Grouping and many other things become vastly easier in 2.0.